# Is it possible to create an embedded browser on a webpage (Using either React.js or Astro)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, astrojs

I am trying to create a web application that I can have 4 separate 'tiles' and each tile is its own web browser so that you can go to a different website. Unfortunately I don't know how web browsers work, so I don't know if this is possible.
I have tried npm packages react-embedded-browser but had no luck and couldn't get it to work properly and don't know where to look for help.

The purpose of the project is so that I can setup 4 dynamic and live 'tiles' which function as screens so that I can display a news channel, and three live price graphs on a single screen for use as a display screen.

Comment: Seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I sincerely doubt you need to embed web browsers *in the browser*. Maybe you're looking for iframes or other types of embedding. Or maybe something else that summarises data rather than directly link to it.

Comment: @VLAZ I am trying to display 4 browser windows at once as if I have divided by computer screen into four separate 'desktops'. Currently the solution in place to do this is a paid for service that creates virtual desktops in which we are opening a separate instance of Chrome on each desktop to display four unique web pages on a single screen in four neat tiles , and we are experiencing problems with it such as the browsers freeze often. Therefore, I would like to create my own solution that I can resolve if it has any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Using [iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) would be the closest thing that could achieve this. Just insert four iframes that redirect to google in your page. So you can navigate in any referenced website from there.

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1"></iframe>
```

Comment: I tried this but iframes do not work for the sites that I tried - I read that only a few websites allow iframes.